# Change Marker with different color image in android GoogleMap V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I created custom marker in android Google Maps API V2 by using below lines of code:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 50, conf); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

canvas.drawText("TEXT", 0, 50, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.map_brown), 0, 0, paint);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(clickedPosition)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                                .anchor(0.5f, 1)
                                    );
```

Now, how can I change the marker image while clicking on the marker from map_brown to map_gray

thanks in advance..

Comment: If you have InfoWindows on each Marker you could solve this by adding a `OnfoWindowClickListener` to your `GoogleMap`.

Comment: I have multiple markers in my map, then how can I change marker inside @Override
 public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
  return null;
 }

Comment: Do you want to change the icon for the time of press or permanently after it is clicked?

Comment: Want to change once click on it...

Answer (score 3):

`addMarker` returns `Marker` object you can interact after it is created.

After you keep a reference to this `Marker`

```
mMarker = mMap.addMarker(...);
```

you can change its icon with

```
mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpWithGraySomething));
```

in `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` callback.

You may also use callback's parameter instead of keeping the reference as a field.